# Crash when deleting pointer object (inherited by QThread) in QList

Tags: c++, pointers, crash, delete-operator, qthread

I have a QList of pointers objects which are inherited from QThread in a multi-threaded application. For example:

```
QList<Object*> m_threadList;
```

and

```
class Object: QThread
```

However, when all threads finished their execution, I need to delete those pointers in order to prevent memory leak. However it always crashed when the program tries to delete the pointer. The funniest thing is that it does not always happen. I am doing something like following:

```
for(QList<Object*>::iterator it=m_threadList.begin();it!=m_threadList.end();it++)
{
    if(!(*it)->isRunning() && (*it)->isFinished())
    {
        disconnect((*it),SIGNAL(ResultsProvider(int)),this,SLOT(ResultsListener(int)));

        (*it)->exit();
        (*it)->deleteLater();
        if((*it)!=NULL)
            delete (*it);    // It always crashes here
    }
}
m_threadList.clear(); // will this cause an issue with deleteLater?
```

This crash does not happen always. Without changing anything, sometimes it will crash when it is trying to delete the pointer and sometimes it will go through smoothly. Has anybody faced similar problem before using any sort of container to store pointer objects (especially QThread)? or can anybody tell where can the problem be?

Comment: Should you use deleteLater and delete at the same time? I mean wouldn't  that guaranty a double delete?

Comment: having the last statement does not make any sense. Just delete that statement and. If the deleteLater is triggered before the delete afterwards, your app will crash.

Comment: @Dominik Selzer, do you mean just have deleteLater() will do the job?

Comment: I believe deleteLater is all you need. You are creating a race that double deletes objects.

Comment: It seems not crashing in the loop anymore. However if m_threadList is a class variable, and it will be reused again after it is cleared. (see edit above). Will deleteLater cause some issue?